# cognito import stuck in creating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a started a Cognito import from the AWS console following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-creating-import-job.html

I can see the job has been created but it when I inspect it in the console and with the API it just says Created, and it has been like that for 15 minutes now.

Is the import job stuck or does it legitimately take a long time to start? I had a look in CloudTrail but couldn't figure out what event I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to click 'start' too - the UI made this seem informational rather than a control.